# Trying to loop links with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I would like to loop a set of links with selenium in python.
I have tried to follow [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309502/loop-through-links-using-selenium-webdriver-python) with no success.
I keep getting the "stale element reference error(I am trying to use WebDriverWait).
my code is as follows:

```
list_of_links = mydriver.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[@class="directory dir-col"]/li/a')
for link in list_of_links:
UI.WebDriverWait(mydriver, 30).until(lambda mydriver:mydriver.find_element_by_xpath('//ul[@class="directory dir-col"]/li/a'))        
link.click()
mydriver.back()
```

I did try placing the webdriver wait command before and after the click and back commands with no success.
any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Richard idea I decided to loop on xPath values and not link text(which can be the same) the code I ended up with is:

```
import lxml.html as lh
import urllib2
from selenium import webdriver

htmlObject = lh.parse(urllib2.urlopen(start_url))
listOfPaths = htmlObject.xpath('//ul[@class="directory dir-col"]/li/a')
listOfLinkPathes = []
for link in listOfPaths:
    listOfLinkPathes.append(htmlObject.getpath(link))
for linkPath in listOfLinkPathes:
   mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(linkPath).click()
   mydriver.back()
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that once you leave the page, the elements in `list_of_links` become stale.

This approach should work for you, assuming each link has different text:

```
list_of_links = mydriver.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[@class="directory dir-col"]/li/a')
list_of_linktext = []
for link in list_of_links:
    list_of_linktext.append(link.text)

for linktext in list_of_linktext:
    mydriver.find_element_by_link_text(linktext).click()
    mydriver.back()
```

Answer (score -2):

For such tasks, I suggest you use irobotsoft web scraper.  This video shows how to do it: http://irobotsoft.com/help/record%20robot.swf