# How to loop clicks with Selenium using Python?

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I am trying to loop clicks with Selenium,
the first click is working but the second gives error below:
`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element could not be scrolled into view`

Here is the code:

```
    def send_keys_dropdown(self,url):
        bot = self.bot
        bot.get(url)
        elements = bot.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@data-tag='globalize']")
        for elem in elements:
            class_of_element = elem.get_attribute("class")
            if class_of_element == 'CsLinkButton':
                elem.click()
                time.sleep(5)
                # close icon
                bot.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data-tag='cmdCancel']").click()
```

How I can click these elements inside loop? Thank you!

Comment: try using a WebDriverWait with expected condition of "ElementToBeVisible".

Comment: For sure you can't use the `elements` reference in your code, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361432/python-selenium-create-loop-to-click-through-links-on-a-page-and-press-button-on/56607061#56607061) for more explanation. And have a question, doe the `globalize' link disappear for the element once you click on the `Cancel` link?

Answer (score 0):

It seems after click action performed element may be inside scroll down or up window form.
following may help you please go through it.

after click action performed add following line.

**((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",
                elem);**
here, **"elem"** is web element of your **click** button.